# jsPDF - Best practices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jspdf

I have been fiddling around with jspdf , but probably taking a wrong approach to goal.

If I use this code.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4'); 
pdf.addHTML($('#previewPage')[0],10,10,function() { 
    pdf.save('BasicInfo.pdf');
});
```

And my content is long I get content cut off on page 1 in pdf,

If I add pagesplit to options

```
pdf.addHTML($('#previewPage')[0],10,10,{"pagesplit":true}function() { 
    pdf.save('BasicInfo.pdf');
});
```

, I get multiple pages , but of course it tries to fit image , and it gets shrink and get result like this.
[image]

I have been thinking of using fromHTML, but it doesn't get all CSS , and it makes every label make new row, no borders etc. Is there a workaround for css problem. Or should i stick with addHTML and try to split columns. 
Just want to hear what are best practices when working with jsPDF and getting html content to pdf